Fastest EF Core Linq extension method for getting entry by GUID
I'm working on an Entity Framework Core project, and I need to retrieve database entries by their GUID value. Currently, I'm using a basic Linq query, but I'm wondering if there's a faster or more optimized way to write an extension method to fetch entries by GUID.
What are some strategies or methods I can implement to improve the performance of my GUID queries? Specifically, how can I make sure the retrieval is as efficient as possible in terms of database access and Linq execution?
So far, I've implemented a basic Linq query using FirstOrDefault to retrieve an entry by its GUID, like this:
var result = context.Entries
                    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Guid == targetGuid);

I expected this to be efficient enough, but after testing with a large dataset, I've noticed some performance bottlenecks. I was hoping the query would execute quickly, even with many entries, but the retrieval time seems to be slower than expected.
I’m looking for alternative approaches or optimizations to improve performance when querying by GUID, especially with large datasets. Is there a better way to handle this kind of query using EF Core and Linq?

There is no substitute for measuring in your environment. Changes such as DB IO and network latency are likely to dominate. I expect you'll find that the DB query execution is the most expensive part and effort put into improving that will have more impact.
Finally: do you want individual requests to be fast or to maximise scalability?

If you are noticing performance issue with large datasets, then check that Guid is indexed. For best performance for retrieving it should be the primary key (although see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264/guid-vs-int-which-is-better-as-a-primary-key for the cons of this approach).

You already have the "Fastest EF Core Linq extension method". See the previous comments, don't look at LINQ for performance improvements. We can't help you if we don't see details of the database structure including indexes.

It is relatively rare for the performance of one simple query like this to cause problems, unless the table has a lots of columns or varchar(max), blobs etc and then the problem is not some much how you retrieve by guid and more what fields you retrieve. A more common problem is how a query like this is used as part of another more complicated query. If that results in multiple database lookups, performance will suffer greatly.

EF just builds an SQL statement, so ultimately what determines the performance is how your backing database handles the SQL that is generated. The primary factor there comes down to indexing. By default, your typical random-like GUID (Guid.New() or NEWID()) make for very poor performing clustered indexes. This can be mitigated somewhat by using a more index-friendly GUID structure like sequential GUIDs (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) or a C# equivalent if you are generating the IDs client-side. Even then you should schedule regular index maintenance jobs on your database to condense the index. (I.e. running daily or weekly)

The GUID column itself has advantages and disadvantages, but to relay on it as a primary key (clustered index) on the long run, is not the best practice. This is because GUID generation is random, and on insertion would cause fragmentation (can cause slower read and write performance due to the disorganized layout on disk).
I am assuming that since this simple query takes time to execute, then the number of data you have is huge.
Here is what you could do:

Use an integer (int/bigint) Id column along with the GUID. This Id column will act as your primary key, while the GUID would be for external use

Use Sequential GUIDS. This is supported by EFCore and would reduce fragmentation by enhancing indexing efficiency which relies on order

Add an integer (int/bigint) Id column as a clustered index, and make the GUID as a non-clustered index.


